# weak convergence in L2

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Let $f_n\rightarrow f$ strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$ for $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open an bounded.
And $g_n \rightarrow g$ weakly in $L^2(\Omega)$. It is said that

$$
\int_{\Omega} f_n g_n \rightarrow \int_{\Omega}fg
$$

Does anyone have a proof for this convergence?

Comment: Use $f_ng_n-fg= f_ng_n -fg_n+fg_n-fg$, the triangle inequality, and the fact that the $g_n$'s are bounded in norm.

Comment: More generally, if $X$ is a Banach space with topological dual $X^\ast$, $x_n\to x$ strongly and $\phi_n\to \phi$ weakly$^\ast$, then $\phi_n(x_n)\to \phi(x)$ with essentially the same proof as suggested in the comment above (or in David C. Ullrich's answer).

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand\abs[1]{\left|#1\right|}$

First, a standard application of Uniform Boundedness shows that $||g_n||_2$ is bounded; say $||g_n||\le A$ for all $n$.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $N$ so $$||f_n-f||\le\frac{\epsilon}{2A}\quad(n\ge N).$$If $n\ge N$ then $$\abs{\int (f_ng_n-fg)}\le\abs{\int(f_n-f)g_n}+\abs{\int f(g_n-g)}=I+II.$$Cauchy-Schwarz shows that $I\le\epsilon/2$ for all $n\ge N$, while weak convergence implies that $II\le\epsilon/2$ for large enough $n$.